# MySQL Select Count ( *) as subquery returns duplicate column error

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to get this simple query to work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM agendas2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_clip_views
     FROM
         (SELECT *
          FROM  uniquevideoviews, agendas2
          WHERE uniquevideoviews.clip_id =  agendas2.clip_id
         ) AS uc
    ) as agendas
```

It returns:

> error #1060 - Duplicate column name 'clip_id'

When I hard code where clause value it works fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM agendas2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_clip_views
     FROM
         (SELECT *
          FROM  uniquevideoviews, agendas2
          WHERE uniquevideoviews.clip_id =  '0123456789'
         ) AS uc
    ) as agendas
```

I know this has to be something simple and I have spent about four hours going in circles.

Comment: Why do you have a triply-nested `SELECT`? Can you show an example of your data and the results you want?

Comment: Why are you nesting all those queries? Can you show us a brief model of those tables and what you want to get from them?

Comment: IMHO, Your query is really bad formed, you are cross joining two tables then filtering one of them and get count of that results, after that cross joining that count with one of them again; so many updates or better queries can be generated ;).

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clip_id is in both tables agendas and uniquevideovies. 
You should use tables\subquery aliases and field names. Or change the inner query like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM agendas2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_clip_views
     FROM
      (SELECT 1
       FROM  uniquevideoviews, agendas2
       WHERE uniquevideoviews.clip_id =  agendas2.clip_id
      ) AS uc
 ) as agendas
```

in this way you avoid the double listing of fields with the same name.

Owever, i believe your query has some more troubles . Why you select twice from agendas2 ? In main relation you dont join agendas2 with uniquevideo views.

Answer (score -2):

Both Tables have `Id` columns , so instead of `select *` use `select <column name>`.